# Input and Output does not show up in python mode

Tags: python, ipython

I am using the `Python` mode with Emacs 25.1.1 to send parts of my python scripts to an ipython console. I have the problem that both the input and the output is not shown in the python window. Whenever I use `C-c C-c` the line is sent to the console and is executed but in the window only an additional line number shows up. Neither the input nor the output is visible.

When I use `C-c C-p` to start the python console I get the error message

```
Warning (python): Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline, yet ‘python-shell-completion-native’ was t and "ipython" is not part of the ‘python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters’ list.  Native completions have been disabled locally.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set `ipython` as a python shell interpreter using the following line:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython" python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")
```

I use `elpy` and it works on my settings, just ignore the warnings and go to the `Python` buffer. Just for information, you need to add `--simple-prompt` because IPython 5 doesn't support Emacs inferior shell anymore as stated in the IPython doc:

> The new interface is not compatible with Emacs ‘inferior-shell’
>   feature. To continue using this, add the --simple-prompt flag to the
>   command Emacs runs. This flag disables most IPython features, relying
>   on Emacs to provide things like tab completion. current doc, you have
>   the following line

More info on the documentation page [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version5.html).

I should also add that beside the issue with IPython, there is a related known bug between Emacs 25 (and >25) and  Python 3.5, it warns about no readline support ([bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24401)).